# Takes 30 mins to respawn in ark

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Whenever my friend joins my ark world on the island on the Xbox one, the respawn time can take up to 39 minutes. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It could be because of your world settings, there are options for respawn times. I found these:

Increase PvP Respawn Interval - Enabling will allow for setting changes in repeat deaths from PvP.

Inc PvP Respawn Interval Check Period - The time in which repeat deaths will still count towards a higher respawn timer. !

Inc PvP Respawn Interval Multiplier - The higher the number the longer respawn timers for each death within the "Check Period" interval.

Inc PvP Respawn Interval Base - The base amount of time for one death from PvP. Each death after within the "Check Period" will use the "Multiplier" setting above.

Found this at https://www.reddit.com/r/ARKone/comments/49jwsw/xbox_one_server_settings_explained_to_my_best/

Comment: care to expand on your answer as to what settings could be causing this?

Comment: Fixed my answer, added much more info

Comment: *Much* better than your original answer.  Please take our tour to learn what we're all about, as your previous answers are very low quality, and liable to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

When you're making the game, scroll down to Enable PvE and check it. Start the server and that should make it work.